# Finding $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$ and $\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}x}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, implicit-differentiation

I'm given the following two relationships between $x, y, z$:
$$\begin{cases} f(x,y,z)=x+y+z-1=0 \\ g(x,y,z)=x^2-2y^2+3z^2-2=0\end{cases} \quad .$$

Question:

> How would I go about calculating $\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}x}$ and $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$ (in terms of $x,y,z$)?

$$\underline{\text{My thoughts}}$$
From the chain rule, I can differentiate (and then divide through by $2$) to get the following two relationships between the differentials:
$$\begin{cases} \mathrm{d}x+\mathrm{d}y+\mathrm{d}z=0 \\ x\mathrm{d}x-2y\mathrm{d}y+3z\mathrm{d}z=0\end{cases} \quad ,$$ but where would I go from here?
Is there something simple that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take the $x$-derivative of both equations to find
\begin{align*}
& 1 + \frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d}x} + \frac{\mathrm{d} z}{\mathrm{d} x} = 0 \\
& 2x - 4y \frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d}x} + 6z \frac{\mathrm{d} z}{\mathrm{d}x} = 0
\end{align*}

Now you have two equations for two unknowns. Solving this system for $\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d}x}$ and $\frac{\mathrm{d} z}{\mathrm{d}x}$ should be a piece of cake.

Comment: Ah. Thank you! Is your system of equations more-or-less equivalent to my second system (just 'dividing' by $\mathrm{d}x$)?

Comment: More or less :)